# Set worksheet as Range without activating/selecting it

Tags: vba, excel

In the following code, is it possible to get rid of the `.Activate` line and not get the "Run-time error 1004", assuming worksheet different than the one I want to be set is selected at the moment of running the macro?

```
Sub PDFbyMarket()
Dim wb1 as Workbook
Dim OBPBudgetByMarket As Range

Set wb1 = Workbooks("PDF")


wb1.Worksheets("OBP_Market_Structure").Activate
Set OBPBudgetByMarket = wb1.Worksheets("OBP_Market_Structure").Range("P9", Range("P9").End(xlDown)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't qualify the second `Range` fully, hence the 1004.

You could use:

```
Set OBPBudgetByMarket = wb1.Worksheets("OBP_Market_Structure").Range("P9", wb1.Worksheets("OBP_Market_Structure").Range("P9").End(xlDown))
```

Or better still:

```
With wb1.Worksheets("OBP_Market_Structure")
    Set OBPBudgetByMarket = .Range("P9", .Range("P9").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to properly qualify all Range calls:

```
With wb1.Worksheets("OBP_Market_Structure")
   Set OBPBudgetByMarket = .Range("P9", .Range("P9").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Note the full stop before **both** Range calls.